# TimeTrigger for 5th Working Day of Month - Scheduled Web Job Azure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-webjobs, webjob, timer-trigger

Im trying to write a TimerTrigger function that runs on the 5th working day of the month(the first day of month except sat/sun).If the first day is sat/sun,it should be run on Monday.So far i know how to run the job at 5th of every month, but how to exclude sat/sunday?

```
  public static void MyTimerFunction([TimerTrigger("0 0 0 5 * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {

            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
```

Comment: Check with `0 0 0 * */1 Mon`

Comment: the above expression would work on 1st Mon of every month instead of the 5th working day of Month.

Comment: The other thing what you do is to run this function Mon-Fri. don't execute the business logic if it's not 5th day or day after sat/sun.

Comment: @user1672994 okay..thanks

Comment: @user1672994 For example this month .. the 5th business day is 7th ,but if i run the code each day and check if its the 5th ,the business logic will get executed anyway . Can you advice on how to do solve this ?

Comment: I've replied to your other question now.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [user1672994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672994/user1672994). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help community members.

"Check with `0 0 0 * */1 Mon`. The other thing what you do is to run this function Mon-Fri. don't execute the business logic if it's not 5th day or day after sat/sun."